# Why is my Pivot query not grouping properly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `Pivot` Query. My issue is that the Query is not grouping properly. Actual `T-SQL` query and its output are shown below:

```
SELECT [Market], [Actual], [Budget]

FROM

(

select distinct Market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by Market) as [RN], 
       sum(rn) over () as [Total],
       cast(CAST(((100.0 * (sum(rn) over (partition by Market))/(sum(rn) over ()))) AS DECIMAL(19,1)) as varchar(10))+ ' ' + '%'  as [Percentage],
       'Actual' as [Type]

from [View1]


UNION ALL

select distinct Market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by market) as [RN], 
       sum(rn) over () as Total,
       cast(CAST(((100.0 * (sum(rn) over (partition by Market))/(sum(rn) over ()))) AS DECIMAL(19,1)) as varchar(10))+ ' ' + '%'  as [Percentage],
       'Budget' as [Type]
from [Budget1]


)xx

PIVOT

(

MIN([Percentage])

FOR [Type] IN ([Actual], [Budget])


) AS pvt_table
```

An extract of my source data (that is, the inner query above):

```
Market           RN     Total   Percentage    Type
Belgium          240    5337    4.5 %         Budget
Belgium          213    5191    4.1 %         Actual
Central Europe    35    5337    0.7 %         Budget
Central Europe   100    5191    1.9 %         Actual
```

An extract of my current output from running the whole query:

```
Market           Actual    Budget
Belgium          4.1 %     NULL
Belgium          NULL      4.5 %
Central Europe   1.9 %     NULL
Central Europe   NULL      0.7 %
```

What I am expecting as result:

```
Market           Actual    Budget
Belgium          4.1 %     4.5 %
Central Europe   1.9 %     0.7 %
```

I was expecting the Grouping by Market to be something explicit in my `Pivot` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**PIVOT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression (`Type` in your case) into multiple columns in the output (`Actual, Budget`, and runs aggregations where they're required on ***any left over column values*** that are wanted in the final output.

So, you have to refine the inner query so that only columns necessary are selected:

```
SELECT [Market], [Actual], [Budget]    
FROM 
(
   SELECT [Market], percentage, type 
   FROM  xxx -- You inner query
) AS src 
PIVOT
(
   MIN([Percentage])
   FOR [Type] IN ([Actual], [Budget])
) AS pvt_table
```

This means you have to leave columns `RN`, `Total` out.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like this

```
create TABLE #Table1
    ([Market] varchar(14), [RN] int, [Total] int, [Percentage] varchar(6), [Type] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Market], [RN], [Total], [Percentage], [Type])
VALUES
    ('Belgium', 240, 5337,        ' 4.5 % ', 'Budget'),
    ('Belgium', 213, 5191,        ' 4.1 % ', 'Actual'),
    ('Central Europe', 35, 5337,  ' 0.7 % ', 'Budget'),
    ('Central Europe', 100, 5191, ' 1.9 % ', 'Actual')
;
 select market,max([Actual])[Actual] ,max([Budget])[Budget] from #Table1
PIVOT (MAX([Percentage]) 
       FOR type in ([Actual],[Budget])) AS pvt
       group by market 

SELECT [Market], max([Actual])Actual , max([Budget])Budget

FROM

(

select distinct Market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by Market) as [RN], 
       sum(rn) over () as [Total],
       cast(CAST(((100.0 * (sum(rn) over (partition by Market))/(sum(rn) over ()))) AS DECIMAL(19,1)) as varchar(10))+ ' ' + '%'  as [Percentage],
       'Actual' as [Type]

from [View1]


UNION ALL

select distinct Market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by market) as [RN], 
       sum(rn) over () as Total,
       cast(CAST(((100.0 * (sum(rn) over (partition by Market))/(sum(rn) over ()))) AS DECIMAL(19,1)) as varchar(10))+ ' ' + '%'  as [Percentage],
       'Budget' as [Type]
from [Budget1]


)xx

PIVOT

(

MIN([Percentage])

FOR [Type] IN ([Actual], [Budget])


) AS pvt_table
group by [Market]
```